# Is it possible to pass multiple messages in Laravel Redirect Back with-> Message

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect back to my page with two messages. I've tried this way:

```
return redirect()->route('index.index')
->with(['warning' => 'warning messages.', 'success' => 'success messages']);
```

but it only brings back the last message of 'success messages'.

Is there a way to get them both back?

Comment: how are you determining that it only "brings back" the last message? you should have access to `warning` and `message` on the next request

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```
return redirect()->route('index.index')
            ->with('warning', 'warning message')
            ->with('success', 'success message');
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it only brings back the last message

Comment: @Nikk96 It's work properly. You can get data with variable warning and success. 
session('warning') and session('success')

Comment: not working also

Comment: if you have 2 "success" it will show only last one

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```
return redirect()->route('index.index')->with(array('warning' => 'warning message', 'success' => 'success message'));
```

And you can get this message in blade file like that,

```
@if (session('warning'))
   {{ session('warning') }}                          
@endif
@if (session('success'))                     
   {{ session('success') }}
@endif
```